# pdfImageFromImageProvider new implementation

Tags: dart-pdf

I updated the flutter version (now v1.20.2) of a legacy application of ours and found this method `pdfImageFromImageProvider` no longer exists. Can anyone help with the alternative?

See current implementation below:

```
var img = await pdfImageFromImageProvider(
      pdf: pdf.document,
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/image.png'),
    );
```

Comment: Check this issue on [Github](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/31)

Comment: The issue suggests that I should use the printing package. I have this imported actually. The code works previously. Only after I upgraded, the issue started. So my guess is that the function was deprecated. The alternative is what I can't figure out.

Comment: I found another issue, with a similar problem. Does [this](https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/576) one help?

Comment: @RohanThacker This absolutely did it. Thanks! You show make an answer out of this comment.